# Why is the code working for the second case?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

```
#include <iostream> 
int *parray(int a[100][100],int m , int n) 
{   int b[200],i, t , j;
    i = 1;
    j = t = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < m ; i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < n ; j++)
    b[t++] = a[i][j];

    //      for(int i = 0; i < m*n ; i++)      
    //      std::cout<<b[i]<<' ';
    return b;
}

int main()
{
  int a[100][100],m,n,*b;
  std::cin>>m>>n;

  for(int i = 0; i < m ; i++)
  for(int j = 0; j < n ; j++)
   std::cin>>a[i][j];

  b = parray(a,m,n);

  for(int i = 0; i < m*n ; i++)
   std::cout<<b[i]<<' ';

  return 0;
}
```

when input is

```
     2 2 1 2 3 4
```

output is

```
     1 2 612675848 32767
```

but when I remove the two "//" just before the return of `parray()` function the output becomes:

```
     1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4
```

Can someone please tell me why code works when I print the value before passing?

Comment: `int b[200]` 200 ain't gonna be big enough bub. It should be `int b[10000]`

Comment: I want to know why it works the second time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`int b[200]` in `parray()` is local to `parray()`. It is removed from the stack from the function returns.(when the scope is over).

If you access it later in `main()` ,you get undefined behavior.

Comment: Thank You. But Why does it work the 2nd time?

Comment: @jymspaul By chance.

Comment: Because when you remove the comments,i.e. `//` , you print the local `b[]` in `parray()`, which will show you what b contains,because it is still in memory.